# Good Libraries for generating .net proxies

Tags: .net, proxy, libraries

I am on the look out for a library that can generate .net proxies for me....

I came through [Castle Dynamic Proxy](http://www.castleproject.org/dynamicproxy/index.html) and it looks a good one.....

Any other libraries which i can give a shot....

Comment: I was about to suggest Rhino Mocks, but then I found out it used Caste Dynamic Prxoy as welll

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Castle Dynamic I think its the best

Comment: I completely agree. Castle's Dynamic Proxy is the one I like the most :)

Comment: @KrzysztofKoźmic That is really a BIG surprise! :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/LinFuPart1.aspx